# How to construct URL with repeating query keys?

Tags: swift, url

I have to construct such URL "myapi?category=69&filters[pa_ram]=83,84&filters[pa_storage]=79"

I tried to build in Playground first using URLQueryItem and URLComponents

```
func callApi(categoryID: String, paramName: String, paramVal: String) {

let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "category", value: categoryID), URLQueryItem(name: "filters[\(paramName)]", value: paramVal)]
var urlComps = URLComponents(string: "myapi")!
urlComps.queryItems = queryItems
let result = urlComps.url!
print(result)

}

callApi(categoryID: "69", paramName: "pa_ram", paramVal: "84")
```

But I'm getting wrong URL "myapi?category=69&filters%5Bpa_ram%5D=84" and also can't understand how should I construct API with repeating query keys. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to have brackets in the URL, I am not sure they are even allowed?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson brackets need to be included in request, this's request from Postman

Comment: Are you responsible for the API? If yes, don't misuse URL query. Your API should recognize that `pa_ram` and `pa_storage]` are filter keys and `category=69&pa_ram=83,84&pa_storage=79"` can be sufficient. If no, please tell the owner of the service that URL query is being misused.

Comment: No, I'm not responsible for API. Our backend dev is working with wordpress. What should I ask him to change?

Comment: Ask him not to use brackets and – as I suggested – recognize the keys as filter keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple filters I would use a Dictionary instead to pass the filter parameters to the function

```
func callApi(categoryID: String, parameters: [String: String]) -> URL {
    var queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "category", value: categoryID)]
    for parameter in parameters {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "filters[\(parameter.key)]", value: parameter.value))
    }
    var urlComps = URLComponents(string: "myapi")!
    urlComps.queryItems = queryItems
    return urlComps.url!
}
```

Note that a dictionary is unordered so if the order is important you could use a custom struct instead and pass an array of it.

To use brackets I would simply do a search and replace of the url string

```
let url = callApi(categoryID: "69", parameters: ["pa_ram": "84", "pa_storage": "79"])
let fixed = url.absoluteString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B", with: "[")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "%5D", with: "]")
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code shows expected request! So I should pass filter parameters in Dictionary.

Comment: No offense but applying `replacingOccurrences` twice is an ugly hack and confirms the query syntax misuse.

Comment: Yes, it was more of a quick fix but I did it outside of the function so it could be easily removed if not needed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it turns out that I need ordered dictionary, may I use OrderedDictionary? https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/tree/main/Sources/OrderedCollections/OrderedDictionary I didn't understand how I could use custom struct

Comment: @Jane I guess you can use that, I haven't used it myself. Another option is to use an array of tuples, change the type of the second parameter to `[(key: String, value: String)]` and when calling the function use `[("pa_ram", "84"), ("pa_storage", "79")]` and you will get the parameters in the right order.